# Amazon Systems Manager alternative on GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, ssm, amazon-systems-manager

Is there a solution/service available on GCP in similar lines of Systems Manager?
My end goal is to run a shell script on GCP VM on specific events.

Like for AWS, via EventBridge I was able to trigger a Lambda Function and the function in turn triggered a SSM command for specific VM.

Is this possible on GCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a Systems Manager equivalent in GCP.

A Pub/Sub subscription from the VMs/compute units which triggers a lambda function (cloud function in GCP) is a suboptimal solution and different from what Systems Manager accomplishes..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of events you have in mind that would trigger running a script but you can check out the tutorial [how to run a function using pub/sub](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub). It shows how to use scheduler based events but [it's possible to use not-scheduled triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers#functions_parameters-python);

> Events are things that happen within your cloud environment that you might want to take action on. These might be changes to data in a database, files added to a storage system, or a new virtual machine instance being created. Currently, Cloud Functions supports events from the following providers:

HTTP
Cloud Storage
Cloud Pub/Sub
Cloud Firestore
Firebase (Realtime Database, Storage, Analytics, Auth)
Stackdriver Logging—forward log entries to a Pub/Sub topic by creating a sink. You can then trigger the function.

And [here you can read on how to implement those triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub).

For example this documentation explains [how to use storage based triggers in pub/sub](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage).

If you provide more details of what exactly you want to achieve (what events have to trigger what) then I can point you to a more direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The approach depends on the exact use case you have in hand. One of the common architecture option could be using pub/sub with cloud functions.  Based on messages published to Pub/Sub topics, cloud functions performing operations of our interest can be triggered/ invoked in the same cloud project as the function.